# How to Remember username or password for login form

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, remember-me

I have created a sample Login form in C# Windows Form Application and what I want is to add Remember username or password feature to my login form.

I just need to provide my username, cause it will remember my password and automatically fill in the password field (Ex. Like in gmail auth).

How could I achieve that?

This is my Login form app:- http://i50.tinypic.com/2pzxjb7.jpg

Comment: Store it somewhere. Where you store it can depend on how secure you want it to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use [.Net's built-in settings API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You can define multiple strongly typed settings with customizable scope; user or application.  There is an interface for it in Visual Studio.  If you open the project properties, you can select the settings tab.  If you don't have a settings file in your project, you can click the link here to have Visual Studio create one.  Once you have one, you can enter in the names, types, scope, and default values of your application settings.

After you set all this up, you will have a class called `Settings` under the `<ProjectName>.Properties` namespace.  You can then use the `Settings.Default` static property to access the default settings, change their values, and call the `Save` method to persist them.

When you start your app up, the persisted settings are loaded and you could programmatically enter them into your user interface.

If all of this is over-kill for your scenario, you could just manually read/write to/from a file in a defined location relative to the user's profile folder.

Comment: i want to store it in Application setting

Comment: i am not getting how to store username or pasword will u please explaine, i am not understanding how to store username or password using setting.

Answer (score 12):

I solved using that.

In you winforms project right click and go to properties, select settings and add name to store data (eg. userName and passUser)

So in you login form add a checkbox remember me.

In you button loggin check if checkbox true, save user and pass

```
        if (checkRemember.Checked)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.userName = textBoxUserName.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.passUser = textBoxUserPass.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

In you load login form add this

```
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.userName != string.Empty)
        {
            textBoxUserName.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.userName;
            textBoxUserPass.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.passUser;
        }
```

Regards.

Comment: Amazing stuff! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try with cookie base remember password

check below reference :

https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/130530/Save-Username-and-Password-in-Cookies-using-C-in-ASPNet/

Answer (score 0):

you can store it in the registry, or database or in a application settings. But I'm not sure how secure you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973902.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
if (checkRemember.Checked)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.userName = textBoxUserName.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.passUser = textBoxUserPass.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

if (Properties.Settings.Default.userName != string.Empty)
{
   textBoxUserName.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.userName;
   textBoxUserPass.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.passUser;
}
```

Comment: A description of your answer would be nice.